# TCP/IP over shared serial bus

Tags: tcp, serial-port, bus, ppp

Is there a serial protocol available for linux that allows for multiple devices to communicate over a serial interface (shared serial bus) with TCP/IP.

My understanding is that PPP is meant for only two devices to communicate over serial (client/server). Where as I am looking for a low level protocol suitable for carrying TCP/IP over a **multidrop** serial bus (only one I can imagine using is RS485).

Comment: You have that wrong. PPP is to *connect* two *points,* but after that it is a fully featured TCP/IP network that supports multiple connections between multiple peers.

Comment: hmm. I am looking at implementing TCP/IP over something like SPI where there are multiple end points on a shared bus. Are you saying PPP is suitable?

Comment: I *said* that your understanding is wrong.

Comment: Yes PPP should be suitable. Since you intend to use TCP, I assume it's not multicast(though not necessarily imppossible in theory), so in that case PPP can always be used for communication between two peers, even if there are more than 1 peer at the SPI end.

Comment: Yes, I want this too. Cannot find an existing IP stack for multidrop RS485. Would be great!

Comment: @michael, have you succeeded in building TCP over serial bus?

Comment: Curious about this, too. @michael did you end up finding something?